# Get data in twig function

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, widget, twig

Is it bad practice to get data from db in twig function or I should pass it to view in controller?

My function is some kind of interface widget that is used on all pages of site admin section. Then on data change I will have to make changes in all actions. But when I get data directly in extension class our teamlead tells that it's bad MVC.

Comment: Use AJAX if you want  to refesh data after page loaded

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you pass it to a view from a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your team leader is right. What you can do is create an action specific to render that widget. I.e create a custom widget, let's say you want to show the number of current active users:

```
class WidgetController extends Controller
{
    public function usersCountWidgetAction()
    {
        return $this->render('widget/usersCount.html.twig', array(
            "usersCount" => $this->getUsersCount();
        ));
    }

    public function getUsersCount() 
    {
        // call the manager and get the result
    }
}
```

Now in all your other twigs you can use

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Widget:usersCountWidget')) }}
```

Comment: This approach is no better. Either allow Twig as a template framework to be dumb and be told what to display, or not. If "not" then the OPs original way is the same as this, in that you are allowing your View to make decisions which it shouldn't. Unless you have a presenter, or front end like React etc.

Comment: @james I appreciate your feedback. This question is a matter of opinion, I'd say there could be no correct answer. I still feel the "render" approach is slightly better exactly because no Twig extension is involved in retrieving any data. But again, it's hard to get a definitive answer and your standpoint is reasonable as well.

Comment: From the official Twig page "Twig is a template engine" a template engine does not know about routing, or calling up the chain to models, services, or controllers. The core issue of this approach is your back end is no longer the authority on how and when things are routed and what models are determined to be needed to be served in the UI. Twig should be the "how" to serve UI, not the "what". If you want front end to determine "what" model to show then you need Javascript at least, but React/VueJS etc at best.

Comment: That said, whatever suits and works is often ok to do, especially in a small application. These things are more guidelines, but they are usually for a reason. Hacking round things can often make it hard to control your application inthe future. But again, horses for courses. Whatever works for your app/team/business :)